# Is there any query which can retrieve all the objects in a Parse.com database?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have to access all the objects inside a Parse.com database one after the other, is this achievable? What do I query for?

I know how to query using a specific object id or by using a specific field. What do I search for so that all the objects are loaded in the resulting search list?

I am working on Android.

Comment: If you have more than 1000 objects, you need to implement paging, as 1000 is the max number of objects you can return. However, you should not need to get all objects in one query. If there is something you need to do with all objects, a scheduled cloud code would probably be a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the objects inside a class, this can be achieved by the following:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("className");
```

This will generate a query for all the objects in your "className" class.

You also said that you want to get the objects one by one. To achieve this, you can iterate through the resulting object array using a for loop for the length of the array.

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries